# Rationality of subseries

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a real sequence. Assume than $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges to a rational number.  Does there exist a subseries which converges to an irrational constant?

Assume now the opposite situation, I.e. the full series converges irrationally, can we find a (non finite) subseries converging to a rational number?

My guess is yes for both the questions, but I couldn't find any actual example. As for the first one, maybe I could extract a Liouville subseries from the geometric series of reason $10^{-1}$?

Comment: For the first, you need to exclude the case that all but finitely many terms are $0$, for then it is of course possible to give examples where all sub-series converge to rational numbers.

Comment: Half of this question is answered by http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/311695/does-every-sequence-of-rationals-whose-sum-is-irrational-have-a-subsequence-wh  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557543/is-it-possible-that-all-subseries-converge-to-irrationals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/311695/81360), we could build a series such that every subseries has an irrational sum.

Conversely, if we have a series such that all but finitely many terms are zero and the rest are rational, then the sum of every subseries will be rational.

However, if we have a convergent series $\sum a_n$ such that infinitely many $a_n$ are non-zero, we may *always* select a subseries that converges to an *irrational* constant.  To prove this, we begin by constructing a subsequence:

- Take $a_{n_1}$ to be non-zero.
- For each $k\geq 1$, take $a_{n_{k+1}}$ to be non-zero, satisfying
  $$
  |a_{n_{k+1}}| < 3^{-k} \cdot |a_{n_k}|
  $$

Now, for any sequence $(\xi_k) \in \{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, we note that the map
$$
\Phi:(\xi_k) \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \, a_{n_k}
$$
is injective (one-to-one), and that each $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k \, a_{n_k}$ is the sum of some (absolutely convergent) subseries.

Since the set $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ is uncountable and $\Phi$ is injective, we may conclude that there are at least uncountably many values that the sum of subseries may attain.  However, there are only countably many rationals.

So, there must exist a subseries whose sum is irrational.

Comment: This is simply amazing. Just out of curiosity, did you make this up or is it a well-known technique?

Comment: I'd say it's a combination of several well-known techniques

Comment: But the solution is my own